# SDL 2.0 won't initialize. Error: "Failed to connect to the Mir Server"

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and using Eclipse CDT.

In my program, I am trying to initialize SDL and if it doesn't initialize then output the error, but SDL_GetError() returns "Failed to connect to the Mir Server". I am sure SDL is installed correctly since I can successfully initialize SDL on another project.

These are the libraries I am using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTzXP.png

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specific version of SDL 2.0 are you using?

Answer (score 1):

bash$ `export DISPLAY=:0`

Setting the DISPLAY run time environment variable fixes it for me — typical X Windows lossage, fails to default to your local display (designed for remote displays) which you'd only know if you'd gone to X11 summer camp.

A complete working example in bash:

```
(cd /tmp && g++ -xc++ - -lSDL2 && (DISPLAY=:0 ./a.out; echo \$? = $?)) <<.
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
.
```

$? = 0

Answer (score 0):

Does the environment you are running on have a windowing system?
This error has come up for me when I'm running tests initializing SDL2 on Travis CI using Ubuntu 14.04. Based on what I've been able to gather from further testing and hints I've gotten from google searches `SDL_Init` when initializing SDL if it is passed `SDL_INIT_VIDEO` (which you are doing implicitly with `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING`), it will try and connect with the windowing system of your machine.
So perhaps try:

```
SDL_Init(0)
```

and then initialize the other subsystems later with:

```
SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)
```

If you do keep in mind that you must quit every subsystem you initialize in this case it's just technically. You would do that like this:

```
SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was using gcc to compile.
When I used g++ to compile it fixes the issue. The [Lazy Foo tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/cli/index.php) also recommends you to use g++ to compile.

If you are having this problem you can try using g++ to compile and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: ... Changing the compiler language fixes runtime errors? Are you sure about this?