# SDL_Init fails with 'SDL_Error: Failed to connect to the Mir Server'

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently going through this website's tutorial on SDL:
(http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/index.php),

using Bash on Windows 10 as the platform. I've installed the SDL package using
`apt-get install libsdl2-dev`
and was able to compile the lesson source code  (http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/01_hello_SDL.zip)
using `g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -w -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL`.

However, when I ran the executable using `./01_hello_SDL`, the program printed out `SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: Failed to connect to the Mir Server`. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25468976/440558

Comment: Tried those solutions already. Nothing.

Answer (score 5):

[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux):

> **This subsystem cannot run all Linux software such as some using a graphical user interface (GUI)** or those in need of unimplemented Linux kernel services.[7] It is, however, **possible to mitigate this by running graphical X Window System applications with an external X server such as VcXsrv or Xming.**

[See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43399827/44729)