# Error Using One SDL Program To Launch Another

Tags: ubuntu, sdl

I am writing a front-end for game emulators in SDL2. My program compiles and works fine except for on Linux (Xubuntu 16.04) when I try to run the selected game. I get a message "Cannot Initialize SDL. Failed To connect to the MIR server." I have tried this selecting to run the MAME emulator from within my program, and also tried running the Mines game which comes with Ubuntu. They both give me this error when trying to run from my game launcher. Yet I can run both of these from outside my game launcher without a problem on the same computer.

[There is an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468976/sdl-2-0-wont-initialize-error-failed-to-connect-to-the-mir-server) talking about setting the DISPLAY environment variable. There already is a DISPLAY variable set in my environment, and its value is 0.0  Maybe my app has a lock on the display and/or the Mir server? If so, I can't figure out or find out how to fix this. I believe the environent is getting passed to the launched program, because I have this near the top of my program:

```
extern "C" {char **environ;}
```

And then call the game I want to launch with this:

```
 int status = posix_spawn(&pid, "/NoQuarter/emulators/mame-177/mame64.linux", NULL, NULL, argv, environ);
```

(I decided to hard-code the path and program for testing purposes, rather than wonder about the exact value of a variable used to represent the game name while I'm debugging this). I don't populate the environ variable myself, but I don't see any examples which do so, so I assume it's done by one of the libraries I'm linking to or something like that.

I am running my program in fake full screen mode, but also tried true full screen and get the same result (that is, I tried both SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN and SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP). This same program works fine on Windows, using Mingw, SDL2, the same version of MAME as I have on Linux, and the CreateProcess() command. Any ideas on resolving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted out. I commented out the 
    extern "C" {char **environ;}
line and now it works. Apparently, just including unistd.h is enough to get the environ variable populated properly (which I already was including in the code), and I guess the line I commented out either conflicted with it or just wasn't going to work even if it wasn't directly conflicting with anything in unistd.h.